# Apresentar dados com o Google Chart - Stacked

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-charts

Estou utilizando o [Google Chart - stacked](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#stacked-bar-charts) para criar um gráfico em meu sistema. Até esta parte está fucionando corretamente, como pode ser visto no exemplo abaixo:

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={%27modules%27:[{%27name%27:%27visualization%27,%27version%27:%271.1%27,%27packages%27:[%27bar%27]}]}.js"></script>

<div id="chart_div"></div>

<script>

  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
             var tdata = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                   ['Estados', 'Concluídos', 'Total'],
                   ['MS', 1, 262],
                   ['RJ', 70, 205],
                   ['SP', 57, 176],
                   ['MG', 0, 82]
                ]);
                var options = {
                    chart: {
                        title: 'Gráfico Clientes',
                        subtitle: 'Total Clientes',
                    },
                    bars: 'horizontal', // Required for Material Bar Charts.
                    hAxis: { format: 'decimal' },
                    height: 400,
                    colors: ['#1b9e77', '#d95f02'],
                    isStacked: true
                };

                var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

                chart.draw(tdata, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
        };
</script>
```

Exemplo no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/randrade/asto8zLy/).

Meu problema está ao mostrar o gráfico (concluídos - Total).

Exemplo: No estado de MS eu possuo um valor total de 262 e concluídos de 1. No estado do RJ eu possuo um total de 205 e concluídos de 70. No gráfico ele está somando as duas datas, como pode ser visto no "tamanho total da barra". Minha dúvida é: Como fazer para a barra seguir o valor total apenas, desconsiderando o valor de concluídos? Eu preciso mostrar os dois valores, mas a barra do gráfico precisa ser por ordem da coluna Total, e não a samotória das duas.

### Edição

A intenção é somente mostrar a diferença dentro de um valor. Por exemplo:

No estado do RJ eu possuo 205 clientes. Desses 205, 70 estão concluídos. Da forma que está, ele está somando (70 + 205) e formando a barra do gráfico com o tamanho desta soma, no caso, 275.

Para tentar explicar melhor, adicionarei essas imagens como exemplo.

Essa é a forma que se encontra o gráfico, como pode ser visto no fiddle acima:
[image: Como está]

E essa é a forma que busco chegar:
[image: Como deveria]

Observando, pode-se ver que o resultado esperado não realiza a soma das duas barras, apenas "marca" um valor correspondente do total.

Comment: Você vai conseguir o mesmo efeito se colocar `concluído` + `não concluído` = `total`. Aí é só apagar o `label` dos não concluídos. e habilitar o `label` total.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O Funcionamento da ferramenta está correto,

Para fazer o que você quer, deve subtrair o TOTAL - CONCLUÍDO

nos valores totais, segue.

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={%27modules%27:[{%27name%27:%27visualization%27,%27version%27:%271.1%27,%27packages%27:[%27bar%27]}]}.js"></script>

<div id="chart_div"></div>

<script>

  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
             var tdata = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                   ['Estados', 'Concluídos', 'Total'],
                   ['MS', 1, 262 -1],
                   ['RJ', 70, 205 -70],
                   ['SP', 57, 176 -57],
                   ['MG', 0, 82 -0]
                ]);
                var options = {
                    chart: {
                        title: 'Gráfico Clientes',
                        subtitle: 'Total Clientes',
                    },
                    bars: 'horizontal', // Required for Material Bar Charts.
                    hAxis: { format: 'decimal' },
                    height: 400,
                    colors: ['#1b9e77', '#d95f02'],
                    isStacked: true
                };

                var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

                chart.draw(tdata, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
        };
</script>
```

Caso queira fazer na mão, basta usar porcentagem

Puxa, as vezes que precisei fazer isso, fiz na mão mesmo com CSS ... Pensa que você tem um valor que é 100% digamos que 300 é o Total, e desses 300 você preencher 100px,... ou seja 33,33%..

Pega uma DIV com width X, pega 33,33% desse widht X e coloca outra div dentro com a cor que quer preencher VERDE ESCURO NO CASO e coloca widht dela igual esse 33,33%

```
<div id="holder" style="height:30px; widht:300px; color:light green;">

<div id="progresso" style="height:30px; widht:100px; color:green;">
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Sim, eu tentei fazer isso. Mas no valor total deverá mostrar exatamente o total. Exemplo: Em seu código o total do RJ está com 135, mas deveria mostrar 205. O gráfico deve dar a entender que de 205 clientes, 70 estão concluídos. Não sei se fui claro, desculpe se estiver confuso.

Comment: Se mostrar 205 como você quer, seu gráfico vai estar meio errado né... Total é soma de 2 coisas... o que está somando com o que? Concluído + XPTO = Total.

Comment: Não exatamente. A lógica neste caso não é saber quantos estão concluídos e quantos não estão, e sim saber do total, quantos estão concluídos. De 205, 70 estão concluídos.

Comment: E se você colocar 2 legends, 1 Concluído 2 Não Concluído? Do modo que você quer com esse plugin não vai rolar...

Comment: Neste caso implicaria em outro tipo de gráfico, o que não seria interessante para mim.

Comment: por que por exemplo, Você pega o concluído e o não concluído, soma e tem o Total... que inclusive aparece no range x do gráfico...

Comment: Eu tentei utilizar `annotation` para fazer a legenda, mas são muitas informações além dessas, e fica poluído o gráfico.

Comment: É.. eu teste isso também... e se você colocasse o Total em baixo e o conclúido em cima? 2 barras horizontais por estado? eu testei e deu, só nao sei se o visual que quer

Comment: Realmente eu tentei também e não ficou muito agradável. Se você conhecer algum plugin que faça isso, poderia adicionar também que eu tenho a liberdade de alterar.

Comment: Puxa, as vezes que precisei fazer isso, fiz na mão mesmo com CSS ... Pensa que você tem um valor que é 100% digamos que 300 é o Total, e desses 300 você preencher 100,... ou seja 33,33%.. pega uma DIV com width X, pega 33,33% desse widht X e coloca outra div dentro com a cor que quer preencher VERDE ESCURO NO CASO e coloca widht dela igual esse 33,33%

Comment: Sim, eu acho que terei que fazer isso mesmo. Só vou ver se mais alguém tem alguma outra resposta, se não, adicione essa parte na sua pergunta que aceito ela mais tarde.